# How to fix SLOW graphics printing on 12.10? Text printing speed is OK

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, printing

Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit dual boot with Windows 7.
Custom PC, nVidia Onboard Graphics.
Motherboard: ECS EliteGroup GF8200A Black Series.
"HP LaserJet 3015" multifunction printer.
Graphics printing fine with 12.04 but *very slow* on 12.10.

Per an article I ran:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
~$ glxinfo | grep renderer
```

Output:

```
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 8200/integrated/SSE2/3DNOW!
```

Do I need to get a graphics card to fix or will software tweaks solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in the terminal:

```
sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current
```

Then reboot.